# AAC Paging loads all pages from api at start of application

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3

I has a problem - when i start an application, PagingSource just loads all available pages from api to recycler.

PagingSource:

```
class NewsPagingSource(                                                                                              
    private val apiService: ApiService,                                                                              
    private val filters: Filters,                                                                                    
) : PagingSource<Int, Article>() {                                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Article>): Int? {                                             
        val anchorPosition = state.anchorPosition ?: return null                                                     
        val page = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition) ?: return null                                        
        return page.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: page.nextKey?.minus(1)                                                       
    }                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                     
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Article> {                                   
                                                                                                                     
        val key = params.key ?: 1                                                                                    
        Log.d("dddd", "------------------------------------")                                                        
        Log.d("dddd", "key - ${key}, pageSize - ${params.loadSize}")                                                 
                                                                                                                     
        try {                                                                                                        
            apiService.getHeadlines(                                                                                 
                q = filters.keyWords,                                                                                
                country = filters.countryCode,                                                                       
                category = filters.category,                                                                         
                page = key,                                                                                          
                pageSize = params.loadSize,                                                                          
            ).articles.toList().let {                                                                                 
                val prevKey = if (key > 1) key - 1 else null                                                         
                val nextKey = if (it.size != params.loadSize) null                                                   
                else key + (params.loadSize / ApiService.PAGE_SIZE)                                                  
                Log.d("dddd", "prevKey - ${prevKey}, nextKey - ${nextKey}")                                          
                Log.d("dddd", "result - ${(it.map { it.publishedAt }).joinToString("\n")}")                          
                return LoadResult.Page(it, prevKey, nextKey)                                                         
            }                                                                                                        
        } catch (e: Exception) {                                                                                     
            return LoadResult.Error(e)                                                                               
        }                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                     
}
```

Repository:

```
        //PAGE_SIZE = 10
        //INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE_MULTIPLIER = 2
interface NewsRepository {
    fun loadLiveNews(filters: Filters): LiveData<PagingData<Article>>

    class Base(
        private val apiService: ApiService,
    ) : NewsRepository {

        override fun loadLiveNews(filters: Filters): LiveData<PagingData<Article>> =
            Pager(
                config = PagingConfig(
                    pageSize = ApiService.PAGE_SIZE,
                    enablePlaceholders = false,
                    initialLoadSize = ApiService.PAGE_SIZE * ApiService.INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE_MULTIPLIER,
                    prefetchDistance = ApiService.PAGE_SIZE / 2,
                ),
                initialKey = 1,
                pagingSourceFactory = { NewsPagingSource(apiService, filters) }
            ).liveData

    }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
    private var _articles: LiveData<PagingData<Article>>
    val articles get() = _articles

    init {
        _articles = newsRepository
            .loadLiveNews(
                Filters("", locationService.getCurrentLocationCountry(), "")
            ).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

PagingDataAdapter:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
) : PagingDataAdapter<Article, RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>(ArticlesDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding =
            NewsListElementBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding, context)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position) ?: return
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: NewsListElementBinding, private val context: Context) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Article) {
            binding.apply {
                // bind to view
                // . . .
            }
        }
    }
}

class ArticlesDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean =
        oldItem.url == newItem.url

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean =
        oldItem == newItem
}
```

In Activity:

```
    private val pagingNewsObserver by lazy {
        Observer<PagingData<Article>> {
            articlesAdapter.submitData(lifecycle, it)
        }
    }
    model.articles.observe(this, pagingNewsObserver)
```

And that is logs:

```
2023-08-16 16:47:51.640 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  ------------------------------------
2023-08-16 16:47:51.641 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  key - 1, pageSize - 20
2023-08-16 16:47:52.724 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  prevKey - null, nextKey - 3
2023-08-16 16:47:52.724 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  result - 2023-08-15T13:50:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T13:38:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T13:30:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T13:14:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T13:07:39Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T13:00:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T12:32:10Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T12:29:43Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T12:29:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T12:19:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T11:57:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T11:53:21Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T11:34:52Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T11:32:34Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T10:52:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T10:49:06Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T10:01:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T09:40:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T09:08:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T09:05:37Z
2023-08-16 16:47:53.222 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  ------------------------------------
2023-08-16 16:47:53.222 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  key - 3, pageSize - 10
2023-08-16 16:47:53.401 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  prevKey - 2, nextKey - 4
2023-08-16 16:47:53.402 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  result - 2023-08-15T08:47:29Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T08:09:47Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T07:12:43Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T07:01:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T05:19:59Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T05:08:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T03:29:52Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T02:08:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-15T01:55:00Z
                                                                                                    2023-08-14T23:54:38Z
2023-08-16 16:47:53.562 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  ------------------------------------
2023-08-16 16:47:53.562 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  key - 4, pageSize - 10
2023-08-16 16:47:54.060 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  prevKey - 3, nextKey - null
2023-08-16 16:47:54.060 30400-30400 dddd                    com.example.newsline                 D  result -
```

It stop loading only when ends pages in Api, but when i use MockApi that generates random data, PagingSource load data until the app is stuck